# React: Passing a Prop in w/ event for setState

Tags: json, reactjs, events, nested, state

I'm working with a nested state object that I have been updating with onChange functions, like so:

```
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({
    customer: [
      {
        name: "Bob",
        address: "1234 Main Street",
        email: "bob@mail.com",
        phone: [
          {
            mobile: "555-5555",
            home: "555-5555"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  const updateSomeStatePhone = e => {
    e.persist();
    setSomeState(prevState => {
      prevState.customer[0].phone[0].mobile = e.target.value;
      return {
        ...prevState
      };
    });
  };

 <p>Update Mobile Number<p>
  <select
   value={someState.customer[0].phone[0].mobile}
   onChange={updateSomeStatePhone}
  >
   <option value="123-4567">"123-4567"</option>
  </select>
```

This gets the trick done.  Currently however, if I want to update multiple state properties via a large form with dropdowns/input fields etc, I have to hard code 6 different onChange handlers for those fields.

Instead, I would prefer to have only one onChange handler, and pass in the state from the form field for the state property that I am changing, but I can't figure out the syntax:

```
  const updateSomeState = (e, prop) => {
    e.persist();
    setSomeState(prevState => {
      prevState.prop = e.target.value;
      return {
        ...prevState
      };
    });
  };

 <p>Update Mobile Number<p>
  <select
   value={someState.customer[0].phone[0].mobile}
   onChange={updateSomeState(e, prop)}
  >
   <option value="123-4567">"123-4567"</option>
  </select>
```

I've tried using different types of syntax to chain the passed in 'prop' value to prevState:

```
prevState.prop = e.target.value;

prevState.(prop) = e.target.value;

${prevState} + '.' + ${prop} = e.target.value; // Dumb, I know
```

But the function never recognizes the "prop" that I pass in from the function. I'm sure there must be a simple way to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a single `useState` hook? I would recommend using `useReducer` or simplifying it a bit with multiple `useState` hooks.

### Multiple `useState` hooks

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = React.useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [mobile, setMobile] = React.useState("");
  const [home, setHome] = React.useState("");

  const getResult = () => ({
    customer: [
      {
        name,
        address,
        email,
        phone: [
          {
            mobile,
            home
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  // Do whatever you need to do with this
  console.log(getResult());

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={name}
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={address}
        placeholder="address"
        onChange={e => setAddress(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={email}
        placeholder="email"
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={mobile}
        placeholder="mobile"
        onChange={e => setMobile(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={home}
        placeholder="home"
        onChange={e => setHome(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit form-with-multiple-hooks]

### Single `useReducer` (with simplified state)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const { type, value } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case "SET_NAME":
      return { ...state, name: value };
    case "SET_ADDRESS":
      return { ...state, address: value };
    case "SET_EMAIL":
      return { ...state, email: value };
    case "SET_MOBILE":
      return { ...state, phone: [{ ...state.phone[0], mobile: value }] };
    case "SET_HOME":
      return { ...state, phone: [{ ...state.phone[0], home: value }] };
    default:
      throw Error(`Unexpected action: ${action.type}`);
  }
};

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  address: "",
  email: "",
  phone: [
    {
      mobile: "",
      home: ""
    }
  ]
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  // Do what you need with state
  console.log(state);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={state.name}
        placeholder="name"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          dispatch({ type: "SET_NAME", value })
        }
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={state.address}
        placeholder="address"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          dispatch({ type: "SET_ADDRESS", value })
        }
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={state.email}
        placeholder="email"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          dispatch({ type: "SET_EMAIL", value })
        }
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={state.phone.mobile}
        placeholder="mobile"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          dispatch({ type: "SET_MOBILE", value })
        }
      />
      <br />
      <input
        value={state.phone.home}
        placeholder="home"
        onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
          dispatch({ type: "SET_HOME", value })
        }
      />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit form-with-reducer]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  Question though. . .is there any advantage of using reducer compared to the lodash recommendation by @ckedar ? That seems to be the cleanest way to reach nested items.

Comment: Well, it seems he has deleted his comment.  Nevermind. . .

Comment: I also noticed that the reducer function is declared outside the component. If I'm importing this component with many other similar components with reducers, will this cause a problem?

Comment: One advantage is that with the reducer you have more flexibility and control the state precisely. You can also do unique things per action/field and add new actions (eg: clear or reset). And it doesn't require adding another dependency (since it's vanilla React).

Comment: one more question here.  What if I need to reach a second "customer" array object in the original state listed above to set the name (state.customer[1].name)?  I can't seem to find the right syntax for that.  I've got the following: 

```
    case "SET_CUST1_NAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          { ...state.customer[1], name: value }
        ]
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

`useReducer` is a better choice for doing this. Examples all over the internet.

Why you shouldn't use `useState` to pass an object is because it doesn't act like `setState`. The underlying object reference is the same. Therefore, react will never trigger a state change. In case you want to use the same `useState` for objects. You may have to implement your own version to extend that (example below ) or you can directly use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook to achieve the same.

Here's an example with `useState` for you to notice the state update on every change.

```
const [form, setValues] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
});

const updateField = e => {
    setValues({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
};
```

Notice the `...form` in there. You can do it this in every update you want or you can use your own utility or `useReducer` as I mentioned.

Now coming to your code, there are other concerns.

1. You are using your `phone` as an array which can be an object. Or better yet separate properties will do as well. No harm.
2. If you have `customers` as an array, you have to loop through the records. Not just update the index by hardcoding. If there's only one customer better not keep the array but just an object. Assuming it is an array of customers, and you are looping through it, here's how to update `mobile`.

```
const updatedCustomers =  state.customers.map(item => {

   const { phone } = item;
   return { ...item, phone: { mobile: e.target.value }}; 
   // returns newCustomer object with updated mobile property
});

// Then go ahead and call `setSomeState ` from `useState`
setSomeState(...someState, { customer: updatedCustomers });// newState in your case is
```

> Instead, I would prefer to have only one onChange handler, and pass in
>   the state from the form field for the state property that I am
>   changing, but I can't figure out the syntax

If you haven't figured that out from the first example. Here's how in short steps.

1. Give your HTML element a name attribute.
2. Then instead use the `[e.target.name]`

```
   return { ...item, phone: { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will look into useReducers.  Unfortunately I cannot change the structure of the state object I'm working with. . .otherwise, I definitely see the value in restructuring the state and using the methods you suggested.

Comment: I didn't say you use it compulsarily. I explained you the reasoning for using what and what NOT in terms of useState and use Reducer. Plus, I pointed the way you are NOT using the loop to update where you should. Another case if it's one time update. Thanks that you felt like appreciating my answer atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash's [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs#set) helper.

```
const updateSomeState = (e, prop) => {
    e.persist();
    setSomeState(prevState => {
      let customers = [...prevState.customers] // make a copy of array
      let customer = {...customers[0]} // make a copy of customer object
      _.set(customer, prop, e.target.value)
      customers[0] = customer;
      return {
        ...prevState, customers 
      };
    });
  };
```

BTW, in your existing `updateSomeStatePhone` you are modifying `prevState` object which is supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this over the reducer?

Comment: @yummylumpkins Less boilerplate code. No change required in update code if adding a new property to customer. We can write reducer using _.set to eliminate boilerplate code, but in general I will go with reducer when dealing with more complex state with interaction/inter-dependency between components of the state.