# React: Reaching Nested State Items w/ Reducer

Tags: json, reactjs, events, nested, state

I'm working with some deeply nested state objects, and thanks to a lot of wisdom from the SO community, [have switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830805/react-passing-a-prop-in-w-event-for-setstate) to useReducer to manage the state.  I can't figure out the syntax to reach deeply nested items or consecutive objects in arrays.  Here's my state object:

```
 const initialState = {
    customer: [
      {
        name: "Bob",
        address: "1234 Main Street",
        email: "bob@mail.com",
        phone: [
          {
            mobile: "555-5555",
            home: "555-5555"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Reggie",
        address: "5555 Pineapple Lane",
        email: "reggie@mail.com",
        phone: [
          {
            mobile: "123-4567",
            home: {
              fax: "444-4444",
              evening: "222-2222"
              }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to reach our second customer, Reggie, and change both his address and home evening phone number (customer[1].address & customer[1].phone[1].home.evening)

I've tried this with my useReducer case statements, but no luck. . .I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined` when I call on these functions (presumably from my dropdown menu, who's value is set to this props I'm trying to change):

```
    case "SET_CUST1_ADDRESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          { ...state.customer[1], address: value }
        ]
      };

     onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                dispatch({ type: "SET_CUST1_ADDRESS", value })
              }
```

And the second for the evening number. . .

```
    case "SET_CUST1_PHONE_HOME_EVENING":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          {
            ...state.customer[1],
            phone: [
              {
                ...state.customer[1].phone[0],
                home: {
                  ...state.customer[1].phone[0].home,
                  evening: value
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };

    onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>
                dispatch({ type: "SET_CUST1_PHONE_HOME_EVENING", value 
   })
   }
```

I understand the need to work with flattened state objects to make all this much easier, but unfortunately the data structure I'm working with is immutable.  Tips/tricks/comments welcome.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

It seems there is an unresolved conflict between using these two case statements, which is causing the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined` during my state changes.  When I try to change the state of two different array objects in the same array, I get the error.  Apparently these two cases cannot exist simultaneously:

```
case "SET_CUST_ADDRESS":
            return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          { ...state.customer[0], address: value }
        ]
      };

    case "SET_CUST1_ADDRESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          state.customer[0],
          { ...state.customer[1], address: value }
        ]
      };
```

These two case statements seem to be causing an error with one another when I call the drop down function on either or, resulting in the aforementioned error. I don't see the connection. Any further input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Incase anyone is having a similar problem and having a hard time working with nested items, I would like to suggest first reading up on [state immutability](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) as recommended to me in my [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/d1psi2/react_reaching_nested_state_items_w_reducer/) on this topic.

I also found (via recommendation) a super way to deal with this type of nested state via something called [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer). It's as easy as making an import statement and then wrapping your case statement in a 'produce' function, which makes a draft of your state that you can directly reference instead of spreading out all layers to make a change.  So, instead of having something like this:

```
case "SET_CUST1_PHONE_HOME_EVENING":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          state.customer[0],
          {
            ...state.customer[1],
            phone: [
              {
                ...state.customer[1].phone[0],
                home: {
                  ...state.customer[1].phone[0].home,
                  evening: value
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
```

You can instead have something like this, which IMO is much cleaner and easier to read/write:

```
    import { produce } from 'immer';
    ...

    case "SET_CUST1_PHONE_HOME_EVENING":
      return produce(state, draft => {
        draft.customer[1].phone[0].home.evening = value
      });
```

And boom! You're done.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you miss this line:

```
case "SET_CUST1_PHONE_HOME_EVENING":
      return {
        ...state,
        customer: [
          state.customer[0],
          {
            ...state.customer[1],
            phone: [
              {
                ...state.customer[1].phone[0],
                home: {
                  ...state.customer[1].phone[0].home,
                  evening: value
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };
```

I mean that you forgot to insert the customer[0] again to the state.

if this was not helpful- you can try to console.log the state before and after ans see which changes you don't want - and which code needs to be fixed according to that.

edit: 
you can use something like this:

```
const stateCustomers = state.customer.slice();
let customer = stateCustomers.find(c => <your condition to find the desired customer>);
customer.phone[0].home.evening = value;
return {
   ...state,
   customer: stateCustomers
};
```

Comment: Is the first state.customer[0] supposed to be spread like the others?

Comment: Also, what if I'm on the 3rd customer? Would I need to include both state.customer[0] and state.customer[1]? What would that look like?  Thanks again for the help @NNH

Comment: I understand, thank you so much. . .did you see my note about a 3rd customer? How would I include that like you did above?

Comment: if you use the second way I've suggested- then you don't need to worry about other customers. If you still want to use the way you did then yes, you have to worry of each other customer in the state.

Comment: Another idea I can think of will be to keep the customers by key e.g.: customerID then your state will look something like this: state: {customer: 1: {...customerDetails}, 2: {...customerDetails}} this way you will be able to change only the customer you need by it's id.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how your edit suggestion works. . .and I can't add any properties/keys to the state, unfortunately (re: customer id).  I know it sucks, but it looks like the easiest/only way to do this is to reference manually like you did in your answer.  But that is still not working for me :( and also, I tried adding customer[2] in there, and that doesn't work either. . .

Comment: my suggestion is to take the array of customers and copy to a new array (since state is immutable), then change the specific customer you want- or by index e.g. customers[index] or by find method, then return the state with the new customers array.